# Captcha and Login script in the same session or in another session?

Tags: php, session-variables, captcha

I've scripted a CMS, but to secure my register.php I want to add a captcha. But you only can access register.php when you're logged it, which means that the logged-in user is in a session. Should I add the script of the captcha in the session that I've already created, or make another session? Is this a good question or a not so good question?

Thanks in advance!

Armando

Comment: A register form that can be accessed only by registered users? That is really weird.

Comment: And yes, you can control the script in the same session...

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan at first glance it looks odd but is actually quite plausible. For example logged in students registering for a course.

Comment: I've pre programmed a Admin user and the register.php is only available for the Admins because its an CMS, i only want to admins to create employees for the CMS not on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same session. Based on your brief, I don't see why using the same session for your captcha and login system would be a problem.

If you are destroying the session at some point (e.g. on logout) and you want to retain the captcha then consider only `unset()` the session variables as required instead of destroying the session. You can still regenerate the session ID.

Comment: Thank you sir, So i could put my script in the session.php file where I scripted my confirm_log_in function and in my logout i've scripted my start session but should i create a function for that? And another function for start_session(); only?